# What's up with my if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Can't figure out what's wrong with my if/else clause. Keeps giving me an unexpected token error.

```
var creditCheck = function(income) {
    var val = income;
};

if (creditCheck > 100); { 
    return "You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card.";
} else {
    return "Alas, you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that.";
}

console.log(creditCheck(75));
```

Comment: Try `if (creditCheck>100) { ` instead of `if (creditCheck>100); { `

Comment: Is there more to this code? Why not just `if (income>100) {...}`?

Comment: @showdev: No, there isn't more to the code. It's a CodeAcademy exercise. The task is to call a function and have it return different things depending on the parameter.

Answer (score 6):

your function creditCheck does not return a value. You have to return it for it to work like you want:

```
var creditCheck = function(income)
{
    var val = income;
    return val;
};
```

Then you actually have to execute that function by using parenthesis:

```
var myScore = 750;
if (creditCheck(myScore) > 100) {
     //dosomething
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work as the op wants. The strings are supposed to be returned from the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your unexpected token is here:

```
} else {
  ^
```

The error causing it to be an unexpected token is here:

```
if (creditCheck > 100); {
                      ^
```

You have an extra semicolon after the `if` statement. That makes your `if` statement being followed by an empty statement which ends with the semicolon. That makes the brackets after the `if` statement form a code block, which is valid by itself. After the code block comes the `else` which is not valid by itself.

---

If you want the code to make any sense, you should have the `if` statement inside the function, and use the parameter instead of the function name in the condition:

```
var creditCheck = function(income) {
  if (income > 100) { 
    return "You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card.";
  } else {
    return "Alas, you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that.";
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what you are trying to do:

```
var creditCheck = function (income) {
    var val = income;
    if (val > 100) {
        return "You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card.";
    } else {
        return "Alas, you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that.";
    }
};
```